# Is it possible to have more than three hues in angular material design provider definitions?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Right now it looks like I am only allowed to define 3 hues in the provider and not allowed to create a new hue called `hue-4` that could be used as `class="md-primary md-hue-4"`. Am I correct in thinking that only hues 1-3 and the default are allowed to be defined?

```
       $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('hc', {'50':'#000000','100':'#ff0000','200':'#ffc285','300':'#ff9e3d','400':'#ff8f1f','500':'#ff8000','600':'#e07100','700':'#c26100','800':'#a35200','900':'#854300','A100':'#ffffff','A200':'#ffdebd','A400':'#ff8f1f','A700':'#c26100'});

    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('other', {'50':'#aff8f2','100':'#ff0000','200':'#34eede','300':'#11cbba','400':'#0eaea0','500':'#0c9286','600':'#0a766c','700':'#075952','800':'#053d38','900':'#03211e','A100':'#aff8f2','A200':'#68f3e6','A400':'#0eaea0','A700':'#075952'});

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('hc-thing')

        .primaryPalette('hc',{
            'default': '100', // by default use shade 400 from the pink palette for primary
            // intentions
            'hue-1': '100', // use shade 100 for the <code>md-hue-1</code> class
            'hue-2': '600', // use shade 600 for the <code>md-hue-2</code> class
            'hue-3': '50'
        })

        .accentPalette('other');

    $mdThemingProvider.setDefaultTheme('hc-thing');
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: No.

Based on angular-mateiral [official document](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme) (v1.1.0):

> Specifying Custom Hues For Color Intentions
>
> You can specify the hues from a palette that will be used by an
>   intention group by default and for the md-hue-1, md-hue-2, md-hue-3
>   classes.
>
> By default, shades 500, 300 800 and A100 are used for primary and warn
>   intentions, while A200, A100, A400 and A700 are used for accent.

So basically, angular-material will only apply class to an element until `md-hue-3`, if you try to use `md-hue-4` or even higher number, it will simply be ignored since there are no related css defined in the framework.

Notice that if you try to add `hue-4` to a palette it will throw out error:

```
// Don't do this, it will break
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('pink', {
      'default': '400', // by default use shade 400 from the pink palette for primary intentions
      'hue-1': '100', // use shade 100 for the <code>md-hue-1</code> class
      'hue-2': '600', // use shade 600 for the <code>md-hue-2</code> class
      'hue-3': 'A100', // use shade A100 for the <code>md-hue-3</code> class
      'hue-4': 'A400', // I know you really want this but it won't work
    })
```

Your best approach would be add a custom css class and override the color there.

Bear in mind that using too many palettes along with too many shades is not recommended by [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-themes)